# Characterization of the Haar measure in terms of the integrals of characters

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, harmonic-analysis

I was reading a paper and I think that they used the following theorem:

Let $G$ compact group and $\mu$ a probability measure on $G$. If 
$$\hat{\mu}(\xi)= \int_G \overline{\xi(x)} d\mu(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if }\xi = 0 \\ 1 & \text{ if } \xi\neq 0\end{cases} \quad \xi \in \hat{G}$$
then $\mu$ is the Haar measure.

Is this theorem true?

I looked on the book An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis of Katznelson that my teacher recommended and I only found the converse of the theorem on a exercise.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: From the context I concluded that $G$ is abelian, even though you did not say so. You may want to edit to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

The linear span of characters is dense in $C(G)$ (the space of complex-valued continuous functions on $G$), by the special case of [Peter-Weyl theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem) (for abelian groups, all [irreducible representations are one-dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/354926/), i.e., they are the characters). This is specifically addressed in the [lecture notes](http://www.mat.ucm.es/imi/documents/20062007_Dikran.pdf) by Dikran Dikranjan.

By the exercise in Katznelson you know that the Haar measure indeed has the property stated in your question. If two Radon measures agree on a dense subset of $C(G)$, they agree on all of $C(G)$ and therefore are the same measure (this is one part of the Riesz representation theorem).