# Is $\textbf{A}^m=\textbf{I}$ diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $\textbf{A} \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be a Matrix and $\textbf{A}^m=\textbf{I}$ where $m\neq \infty$. Show (with Jordan normal form) that $\textbf{A}$ is diagonalizable. I have no clue how to do that...

Comment: I wouldn't use Jordan normal form either.

Comment: Hint: the polynomial $p(x) = x^m - 1$ factorises into distinct linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What are the roots of $\;x^m-1\;$ ? How many of them are different?

Comment: To use Jordan: compute the powers of a Jordan block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $A$ be a complex matrix such that $A^n = I$, show that $A$ is diagonalisable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1189330/let-a-be-a-complex-matrix-such-that-an-i-show-that-a-is-diagonalisable)  There are other versions of this question on math.SE with solutions of varying approaches and levels of detail.  See also e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2676557/prove-that-t-is-diagonalizable-if-and-only-if-the-minimal-polynomial-of-t-has-no ($T$ is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial of $T$ has no repeated roots)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. We use the following:

a matrix $M$ is diagonalisable iff its minimal polynomial is the product of distinct linear factors.

Now, can you see how to apply this to $A^m -I=0$?. Hint: the minimal polynomial will have to divide $t^m - 1$

Answer (score 0):

Using the Jordan normal form:

We have to show that all the blocks have size $1$. Now, if $A^m=I$, then it is easy to see that for the Jordan form $J$ we have $J^m = I$, so for every block $J_{d, \lambda}$ we have
$$J_{d, \lambda}^m = I_d$$

However, if $d>1$, then the elements of $J^m_{d, \lambda}$ just above the diagonal have value $m$, so not $0$. Therefore, all the $d$'s must be $1$, all the blocks have size $1$, so $A$ is diagonalizable.