# Does $G/ker(\rho)$ being abelian tell us anything special about the representation $\rho$?

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $\rho$ is a representation such that $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(V)$.  Suppose that $G/ker(\rho)$ is Abelian.  What does this tell us about $\rho$?  In particular, how can we reach the conclusion that $\rho$ is the direct product of one-dimensional representations of $G$?  I feel Maschke's theorem would be useful here, but I need some guidance.

This is an assignment question, so I am mainly looking for hints not full solutions.  I want to figure it out on my own with hints and I hope to delete the question once I get an idea.

Comment: *I hope to delete the question once I get an idea.* This is improper etiquette here: your posts are meant to help the community, and not only you. Please do not do this now, or ever.

Comment: However it is not necessarily improper etiquette to ask for hints instead of full solutions. We do want to encourage both doing and showing own work on problems.

Comment: @mathreadler Whether askers should show extensive work is not universally agreed upon. Really it's used as a barometer to decide if the asker is trying to get free homework solutions, which some believe is somehow unjustified, even though copying down a solution you don't understand is more likely to hurt you than help.

Comment: @MattSamuel I did not mention *extensive* work but I do see your point.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $V$ is a complex vector space. This implies that the image of $\rho$ is commutative. You may use results about representations of finite commutative groups:

[Complex finite dimensional irreducible representation of abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354926/complex-finite-dimensional-irreducible-representation-of-abelian-group)

Since a representation of a finite group is the sum of irreducible representations, you deduce that $\rho$ is the sum of irreducible $1$-dimensional representations.