# Is there an irreducible representation of $U(1)$ which is not one dimensional?

Tags: representation-theory, banach-spaces, topological-groups

**Note**: A "representation" for me is a continuous linear action of a topological group on a complex topological vector space. A "subrepresentation" is a closed action-invariant linear subspace.

**Question**: Is there an irreducible representation of $U(1)$ which is not one dimensional? An example on a Banach space would be particularly nice.

**Effort**: Such representation cannot be a representation on a Hilbert space. Maybe we can take $1\leq p\leq\infty,p\neq 2$, consider the action on $L^p(S^1)$ and find some irreducible subrepresentation $V$ (the topology of our chosen $V$ must be a topology which cannot be induced from an inner product, otherwise this will not  work).

Comment: Maybe relevant:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354926/complex-finite-dimensional-irreducible-representation-of-abelian-group
?
Maybe there is an analogous result for your general form of representation?

Comment: @user357980: The argument stated in your linked question seems to use Schur's lemma (what is referred to as a "previous exercise" there). I am not aware of a version of Schur's lemma outside the Hilbert space world (but that would be very interesting!).

Comment: @user357980: Actually, it seems that there are versions of Schur's lemma for Banach spaces, see "A primer on spectral theory / Aupetit", Thm 4.2.2 (so we probably need to look outside of the Banach space world as well).